# XCom Enemy Within Long War on OS X

Tags: xcom-enemy-within, xcom-long-war

Has anyone tried applying the Long War mod to a Mac running OS X with Enemy Within installed from the Mac App Store?  If so, how stable was the gameplay after applying it?  The creators of the mod do not believe it will work, but they welcome Mac users to try it on the page linked to below.

http://www.nexusmods.com/xcom/mods/88/?

Regards,
Sam

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about running something without meeting the system requirements.

Comment: Nah, XCom is available on Mac nowadays; he wants to know if certain mods work okay with it.

Comment: Thank Shadur, that is exactly what I am asking.  I believe someone has done it since I posted this back in June.  There are instructions available on another site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you're not yet aware, the Beta 13 version of the mod (released 27th August) is available as a Mac OSX installer - via the files section of the link in your question.

I've successfully used this to install and play the mod on a the Steam version of the game on a Mac.
I do not know if it works or not with the iTunes version of the game.

The install requires a little more effort than the Windows version - a change to the hosts file is required, for example - the readme docs with the download explain this for you, so read them first.

Answer (score -4):

dude I don't know if  you already read this  but http://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/2c603p/getting_long_war_to_work_on_osxsteam/

Comment: Please, don't post link only answers. The link may become broken in the future or the content edited, and the info is lost. Besides, People come here to find the answer, not a link to another site where I have to look around and hope that I find the answer in somewhere there.